# Windows 10: Different Directory Listings under Different Accounts

Tags: windows, windows-10

Consider the following on a freshly-installed Windows 10 environment with a single account named "User":

1. Logged in as "User", I create a file named "Test.txt" on my desktop and copy this to "C:\". Windows displays a dialog warning me that this cannot be done unless permissions are elevated; I do this.
2. With this file now at the top level of my C drive, I now open CMD.exe as Administrator (by right-clicking the file from Explorer and choosing "Run as Administrator").
3. I CD to my C drive, and get a file listing of everything. My previously-copied text file is not there.
4. Next, still using the elevated copy of CMD I copy the Notepad executable from my Windows directory to the same top level of C; performing a "dir" confirms that this file is there.
5. Finally, I close CMD and go back to Explorer. Whilst I am still able to see my test text file as before, the just-copied executable for Notepad is not visible.

Is this behaviour due to some kind of permission/account differences - should I not expect to see files in C when running CMD as admin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing UAC Virtualization in practice. When I first saw it I was stumped.  It was developed for Windows 7 and continues in Win 10. If a normal user writes to one of the protected areas, Windows stores it in the users profile where it is only accessible by that user.  Works with registry changes as well.

More from MS [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works)